# Symbol.iterator differ in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm currently having some strange behaviour when using `Float32Array` on different browsers.

On Chrome (Windows), these are the results of my tests :

```
const a = new Float32Array(0)
Symbol.iterator in Object(a) => returns true
```

On Chrome (Android), these are the results of my tests:

```
const a = new Float32Array(0)
Symbol.iterator in Object(a) => returns false
```

How is this even possible? The results are opposite so I can't even test the rest of the application correctly.

The 2 devices are running on the latest version of Chrome

Comment: Well, it is possible. For example Chrome on Android don't have addons. Firefox is more close to desktop version. More interesting is WebGL (eg. on Huawei P20) - Chrome for Android shows lower maximum texture size (when you query context parameters) than Firefox while on PC there are no differences. It looks like we need some polyfills for android devices.

Comment: @Zydnar I tried some polyfills that I found online for this, but they don't really seem to work, can this be because I'm using babel?

Comment: It is possible but the easiest workaround is defining own iterator `myOBJArrOrWhatever[Symbol.Iterator] = function* (){/* your logic goes here */}` or you can define own class that extends Float32Array with method [Symbol.Iterator]

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/@@iterator), `Symbol.iterator` is defined on typed arrays in Chrome from version 38 onwards.

Comment: @Zydnar The problem here is that this code is used in one of the dependencies I'm using so I can't really change that.

Comment: @trincot It is indeed defined and I can use them, but the result it's giving is different.

Comment: Doesn't `Symbol.iterator in Object(a) === false` mean that this symbol property is *not* defined on the typed array? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't really know the exact definition of this (it's coming from Babel), I only know that the returning result is different while the input is the same...

Comment: @Trisma if polyfills don't work, try reporting this as issue, they usually fix critical problems quite fast.